# How to remove unneeded tool windows in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm talking about this:

[image]

*(For those wondering: It's the "Capture" and "Maven Project" tool window.)*

I've tried looking at `View` -> `Tool Windows`, but it seems like I can only *add* a new window, not *remove* one.

Anyone know how to do this? It's not a big of a deal I know but it's still nice if I could get rid of those windows (as I'd never use them anyway).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to close them anyways? You can just right click and hide them. They are not blocking your view or anything

Comment: I can't hide them; the only thing I can do is to minimize them. As of why, well I already told it in my question that I've never used them, I don't see myself using them in the future, and I'd like to keep my workspace clean. It'd be nice if I could somehow make 'em completely - if that's not too much to ask.

Comment: if you click the left-bottom most icon (the grey thing under <terminal>) then all of your side-icons hide. I do this and use the keyboard shortcuts for opening the windows like: <ctrl + 1> for the project window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the Jetbrains documentation says you can do it using the 'remove from sidebar' option of the tool windows' context menu:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#tw_button

But in Android Studio 1.5.1 I don't see this option, so maybe it hasn't made its way to AS yet.

Comment: Now this is what I've been looking for. Shame that we still not getting that option yet in AS (presumably because the current AS – that is not in beta – is based on a much older IntelliJ than the one that docs subject to).